# How to tell if Azure Container has Virtual folders/directories?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a project that is reading the data from a Azure Blob and saving that data into an Object. I am currently running into a problem. The way my code is set up now - it will read all the .txt data within a container if there are no Virtual Folders present.

However, if there is a virtual folder structure present within a Azure Container 
my code will error out, with a `NullExceptionReference`. My idea was to do a `if` check to see if there was Virtual Folders present within an Azure Container if so execute `//some code`. Is there a way to tell if there is a virtual folder is present?

---

**ReturnBlobObject()**

```
private List<Blob> ReturnBlobObject(O365 o365)
    {
        List<Blob> listResult = new List<Blob>();
        string textToFindPattern = "(\\/)";
        string fileName = null;
        string content = null;

        //Loop through all Blobs and split the container form the file name.
        foreach (var blobItem in o365.Container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true))
        {
            string containerAndFileName = blobItem.Parent.Uri.MakeRelativeUri(blobItem.Uri).ToString();
            string[] subString = Regex.Split(containerAndFileName, textToFindPattern);

            //subString[2] is the name of the file.
            fileName = subString[2];
            content = ReadFromBlobStream(o365.Container.GetBlobReference(subString[2]));

            Blob blobObject = new Blob(fileName, content);

            listResult.Add(blobObject);
        }

        return listResult; 
    }
```

**ReadFromBlobStream**

```
    private string ReadFromBlobStream(CloudBlob blob)
    {
        Stream stream = blob.OpenRead();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by refactoring my code. Instead of using Regex - which was returning some very odd behavior I decided to take a step back and think the problem. Below is the solution I came up with.

**ReturnBlobObject()**

```
private List<Blob> ReturnBlobObject(O365 o365)
    {
        List<Blob> listResult = new List<Blob>();

        //Loop through all Blobs and split the container form the file name.
        foreach (var blobItem in o365.Container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true))
        {
            string fileName = blobItem.Uri.LocalPath.Replace(string.Format("/{0}/", o365.Container.Name), "");
            string content = ReadFromBlobStream(o365.Container.GetBlobReference(fileName));

            Blob blobObject = new Blob(fileName, content);

            listResult.Add(blobObject);
        }

        return listResult; 
    }
```